# S3 - grant access to create buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Is there a sample IAM Policy that grants access to a single IAM user to let them create and manage their own S3 buckets?

Comment: If you're going to allow an individual IAM user to create buckets and fully manage them then you're likely to need s3:*. If, however, you simply want to provide isolated S3 storage for individual IAM users, then see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-policies-s3.html#iam-policy-ex1.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon S3 doesn't really have the concept of a person's "own" bucket. Buckets are **owned by the AWS account**, not a particular user.

You can put a policy on an IAM User that gives them permissions for a **specific bucket**:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"]
    },
    {
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, this does not grant permissions to **create a bucket**. For that, they would need permission on `"s3:createBucket"`, but please note you'd then need to code the name of that bucket into a new policy.

Or, you can use [IAM Policy Variables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html) to create a generic rule that allows users access to their own subdirectory (prefix) **within a shared bucket**.

You might even be able to use Policy Variables to grant permissions on a bucket if the bucket name has the user's name in it too. That starts to get a bit tricky.